# Git commit count per day

Tags: git, commit

I have a branch called `development`. Now I want to know how many commits happened per day.

I tried this command, but it is counting all commits from the branch

```
git shortlog -s -n
```

Answer (score 66):

Short and sweet:

```
git log --date=short --pretty=format:%ad | sort | uniq -c
```

Example output:

```
      1 2017-12-08
      6 2017-12-26
     12 2018-01-01
     13 2018-01-02
     10 2018-01-14
      7 2018-01-17
      5 2018-01-18
```

Explanation:

- `git log` is a prerequisite, obviously.
- `--date=short` sets our `date-format` to `YYYY-MM-DD`, which (A) is all we need and (B) will subsequently alphabetically `sort` into chronological order.
- `--pretty=format:%ad` tells `git` that we only want to get each commit's `a`uthor `d`ate in our preferred `date-format`. If you wanted, you could instead use `cd` for `c`ommit `d`ate, but that tends to get a lot less useful as soon as you `cherry-pick`, `rebase`, etc.
- `| sort` is needed for `uniq`, as it only checks for adjacent duplicates. And of course, we almost certainly want the dates to be ordered at the end anyway.
- `| uniq -c` counts the number of adjacent duplicates for each `YYYY-MM-DD` and prepends that count to the date.

---

If you want that as a tab-separated date then count, for input into a graphing engine or suchlike, then just pipe the above result into

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS = "\t"} {print $2, $1}'
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$ git rev-list --count --since=<start-date> --before=<end-date> <ref>
```

For example, to get the number of commits done yesterday in the current branch:

```
$ git rev-list --count --since=yesterday --before=today HEAD
```

Absolute dates are also accepted:

```
$ git rev-list --count --since=2016-03-02 --before=2016-03-03 HEAD
```

Answer (score 4):

I've tried with:

> git log | grep Date | awk '{print " : "$4" "$3" "$6}' | uniq -c

And it works. You'll get something like:

```
   5  : 3 Mar 2016
   4  : 2 Mar 2016
   8  : 1 Mar 2016
   [...]
```

I found the command [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12099/number-of-commits-per-day-in-a-git-repository).

Comment: Combine with grep "your date". This only works for one specific day. The solution above has ranges.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily wasteful since it pipes a normal, full `git log` instead of only the minimum it needs per commit. Also, you don't `sort`, which could lead to `uniq` returning bad results and/or screaming at you, because neither author (what you show here) nor commit dates need be in chronological order.

Comment: Also, more simply, what if a commit message contains the word Date...?

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), you have another option, since "[`git shortlog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c112d8d9c2687cb6443b628e38aa446e335fb21a/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog))</sup> learned to group by the format string.

See [commit 7b11234](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b11234e3bee123d6d48ed175f11b26b54fa67c6), [commit 9c10d4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c10d4ff2401cd5908e4e874c403fadebb2ac0b3), [commit 10538e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10538e2a627b8ab14f977c868f2975a2acb4ed4d), [commit 3dc95e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3dc95e09e1355ebde472bd5be37aa7b29ef774d3), [commit b017d3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b017d3dae9fe5a5b636b8f7a5235cee2b1b90332), [commit 0b293df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b293df9642bc8731e45e636ef8f1c0c5749d4b2) (24 Oct 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
See [commit 251554c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/251554c26931bec94e86d0e5740084d6116dd263) (24 Oct 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit c112d8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c112d8d9c2687cb6443b628e38aa446e335fb21a), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`shortlog`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3dc95e09e1355ebde472bd5be37aa7b29ef774d3): support arbitrary commit format `--group`s
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> In addition to generating a shortlog based on committer, author, or the identity in one or more specified trailers, it can be useful to generate a shortlog based on an arbitrary commit format.
>
> This can be used, for example, to generate a distribution of commit activity over time, like so:
>
> ```
> $ git shortlog --group='%cd' --date='format:%Y-%m' -s v2.37.0..
>    117  2022-06
>    274  2022-07
>    324  2022-08
>    263  2022-09
>      7  2022-10
> ```
>
> Arbitrary commit formats can be used.
> In fact, [`git shortlog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3dc95e09e1355ebde472bd5be37aa7b29ef774d3/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog))</sup>'s default behavior (to count by commit authors) can be emulated as follows:
>
> ```
> $ git shortlog --group='%aN <%aE>' ...
> ```
>
> and future patches will make the default behavior (as well as `--committer`, and `--group=trailer:<trailer>`) special cases of the more flexible `--group` option.
>
> Note also that the `SHORTLOG_GROUP_FORMAT` enum value is used only to designate that `--group:<format>` is in use when in stdin mode to declare that the combination is invalid.

`git shortlog` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3dc95e09e1355ebde472bd5be37aa7b29ef774d3/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt#L53):

> [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)). Useful with `--group=format:<format>`.

`git shortlog` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3dc95e09e1355ebde472bd5be37aa7b29ef774d3/Documentation/git-shortlog.txt#L67-L69):

> - `format:<format>`, any string accepted by the `--format` option of
>   'git log'. (See the "PRETTY FORMATS" section of
>   [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).)

Comment: What does `v2.37.0..` in the first command mean? It does not seem to work...

Comment: @JonasKello It is a [tag from the `git/git` repository](https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v2.37.0).

Answer (score 0):

> As seen in the [answer by @underscore_d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329147/15167500), with the following command, you can request the number of commits submitted on a daily basis.
>
> ```
> git log --date=short --pretty=format:%ad | sort | uniq -c
> ```

Utilizing this, I have prepared the commands necessary for monthly and yearly queries.

#### Months

Using the awk command, **keep only the 6th and 7th characters from the date**, representing the numbers indicating the **month**.

```
git log --date=short --pretty=format:%ad | awk '{print substr($1, 6, 2)}' | sort | uniq -c
```

**Example Result**

```
12 01
60 02
12 03
13 04
10 05
 4 06
24 07
30 08
10 09
 2 10
89 11
46 12
```

#### Yearly Months

Using the awk command, **keep only the first 7 characters from the date**, representing the numbers indicating the **year and month**.

```
git log --date=short --pretty=format:%ad | awk '{print substr($1, 1, 7)}' | sort | uniq -c
```

**Example Result**

```
 1 2017-01
 6 2017-02
12 2017-03
13 2017-04
10 2017-05
 7 2018-01
 5 2018-02
13 2019-08
 4 2020-02
14 2020-07
 2 2020-11
 1 2021-01
```

#### Years

Using the awk command, **keep only the first 4 characters from the date**, representing the numbers indicating the **year**.

```
git log --date=short --pretty=format:%ad | awk '{print substr($1, 1, 4)}' | sort | uniq -c
```

**Example Result**

```
19 2017
42 2018
89 2019
 3 2020
```