# Get commit count for each day along with date along in GitHub API

Tags: github

I am writing Node API to extract data from Github repo.
While doing so, I find a need to count commit for a repo for each day along with date.

I have tried this [github api doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-weekly-commit-count-for-the-repository-owner-and-everyone-else)

I don't want to do this in this way

```
  https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/
```

An alternative way of doing this can be is to follow this link down below , but this also do not provide date along with week.

[weekly commit count](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#get-the-weekly-commit-count-for-the-repository-owner-and-everyone-else)

Any thought/suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. You should be a bit more specific (e.g. you want a script, ..) as well should you also tell us what you already tried. Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for mentioned important links

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
[Git commit count a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769003/git-commit-count-a-day)

https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12099/number-of-commits-per-day-in-a-git-repository

Comment: NO , as this is for git cli, I am asking for a Github API